# Why does blood come out of leach when salt is put on it?

Tags: osmosis

I know ***osmosis*** is the reason for the water to come out of *cells* - When you sprinkle salt over a leech, it creates concentration gradient and forces the water out of the cells. But why does a lot of *blood* come out too ?